# Masyu-making game

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, game, masyu

> Two players are playing a game on a $4\times4$ board. The players take turns adding either a white circle or a black circle into any empty square, so that the board makes a solvable [masyu](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/masyu.html) puzzle (with one or more possible solutions). The winner is the player who first makes the position **uniquely** solvable (i.e. a puzzle which only has one possible solution).
>
> [image]

What move should the first player start with?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Up to symmetries of the board, there aren't very many possible moves for the first player:

> [image]
>  There are only five moves: black in A, black in B, black in F, white in B, and white in F.
>
>  Black in A doesn't work; the second player responds with black in K.
>  Black in B doesn't work; the second player responds with black in O.
>  Black in F doesn't work; the second player responds with black in P.
>  White in B doesn't work; the second player responds with black in K.
>  So the only possible answer is white in F.

Does this strategy work?

> Let's check all possible responses to white in F (again, ignoring symmetry):
>  Black in A makes the puzzle unsolvable.
>  Black in B: respond with black in L.
>  Black in C makes the puzzle unsolvable.
>  Black in D: respond with black in J.
>  Black in G: respond with black in M.
>  Black in H: respond with black in M.
>  Black in K makes the puzzle unsolvable.
>  Black in L: respond with black in B.
>  Black in P: respond with white in B.
>
>  White in A makes the puzzle unsolvable.
>  White in B: respond with black in P.
>  White in C: respond with black in L.
>  White in D makes the puzzle unsolvable.
>  White in G: respond with black in N.
>  White in H: respond with black in J.
>  White in K: respond with white in L.
>  White in L: respond with white in K.
>  White in P makes the puzzle unsolvable.
>
>  So this first move does indeed work, and lets the first player win on their next turn.

Comment: The two possibilities involving P and B are not uniquely solvable. rot13(Sbe juvgr va C, lbh pna erfcbaq jvgu juvgr va W, X be A. Sbe oynpx va C, lbh pnaabg jva.) This doesn't change the first move though.